Is there a way to sync a CUDA kernel with another program
I have a CUDA kernel running in a file, let's call it file1.cu. I am doing cudaMalloc and cudaFree in file1.cu. I have another file called file2.cu which I want to sync with these two events, and know when allocation and deallocation occurred. Is this possible?
I am using cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total) in file2.cu and measuring the amount of free memory to determine if allocation has occurred.
cudaMemGetInfo in file2.cu does reflect the allocation when repeatedly printing for the duration of file1's execution, but I want the exact time.

cudaMalloc and cudaFree are regular host-side functions. You can use whatever inter-thread communication you would normally use, like callbacks, observer patterns, atomic flags, std::barrier etc. There is really nothing CUDA-specific about this.

Maybe CUPTI's CUDA runtime API callbacks  could be helpful here.

It depends on what you mean with another program. If you mean another process with its own memory, then you would need to send a message through sockets to do so, then you can add all the information in a datagram. If its another thread within the same process, you could consider message buffers that are thread safe to pass on the information you need. Personally I do not know of a way to do it with CUDA API calls, and if you intend for your application to spawn multiple process across different computers (think HPC), then sockets might be your only option.

I do not want to spawn processes across computers, I am just trying to see if one CUDA program can be synced with another on the same computer. I am launching both programs using a bash script.

@AnirudhT Given how vague your requirements are, there are an abundance of IPC-mechanisms on Linux that can do what you want. Sockets, pipes, shared memory, POSIX message queues, MPI, …. Pick your poison. Maybe start with something like Boost.Interprocess. None of these have anything to do with CUDA, it's all just regular C/C++

If its within the same process, the easiest way I can think of is using the std::atomic library to create atomic variables that you can write all this info into.
